# CMake generates too long pathnames on Makefile generation

Tags: path, windows-xp, cmake

A current project has a pretty complex structure (which I can't change) and it uses CMake.
But I have troubles to create a Makefile which can be compiled.

Mainly the problem is: If my projects is stored in `D:\a\b\c\` , some source in `D:\a\b\c\src\d\e` and the build folder in `D:\a\b\c\build`, cmake creates some folders like `D:\a\b\c\build\SubProjectName\CMakeFiles\DetailedSubPrjectName.dir\D_\a\b\c\src\d\e`. I think you get the point - it happens that the resulting paths are longer than 260 characters.

I can not flatten the project structure(not my code). The only way to make this work is to put the whole project somewhere higher in the folder structure - (very)near to the drive root (I've got about 10-15 chars to spare). But this isn't really acceptable, sometimes there are more characters needed.

Is there any way to either convince CMake to create flat structures in the build dir or to use longer pathnames (in WinXP)? Or some other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS) to shorten your paths a little bit but apparently it has a record of not working…

Anyway the problem comes from Windows more than CMake and you would better try to increase the maximum path length on your system. Unfortunately I can't help you here.

However, CMake should probably be aware of path length limits on Windows XP so I recommend you [file a bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/my_view_page.php) so CMake developers can do something about it.

Comment: The issue is still there if I use CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS. My current solution is to use a temporary directory (Like c:\tmp\build) and adding a post-build copy. Not the best solution I guess, but the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to circumvent this problem is to use `subst b: c:\my\long\source\dir` and then work on the new B: drive. 
You will also have to purge your build directory.